# How to get 'report_py3o' for Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I got 'report_py3o' module which developed by OCA for  Odoo 10
https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine

but i couldn't found it for odoo 9.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't made for Odoo 9 yet? What about backporting it by yourself?

Comment: it's available in pull request. but i don't know how to. here is the link https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/pull/73